# What skills are necessary to become President(Rector, Chancellor)?

Tags: administration

Recently on my University he dies and now I was wondering how should be the ideal candidate. Taking into account that he/she is the one above all the faculties.

1. Does he/she need to have a Doctor degree? and of what kind?
2. Does he/she needs to speaks more than just one language?

Comment: Maybe you could explain a bit what the job of Rector involves at your university. For instance, US readers will have a hard time making sense of your question otherwise, since the title of Rector doesn't exist in most US university systems.

Comment: I am certain this is country-dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will vary hugely between countries and individual universities.

In the UK most universities are formally led by a Chancellor: see [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chancellor_(education)) for more information. Since their role is largely ceremonial, what is important is that they are people seen as being prestigious enough to represent the university. The current Chancellor of Oxford is Lord Patten, who used to be Governor of Hong Kong and chairman of the BBC trust. To the extent that a chancellor may sometimes publicly advocate for the university (especially for funding) it's also valuable for them to be something of an 'establishment' figure on good terms with those in positions of power.

If you mean to ask about the qualities of the person who actually controls the university (which in the UK would normally be the Vice-Chancellor) that deserves a separate answer, but one would expect them to be experts in the education sector and experienced at leading large complex organisations.

To answer your numbered questions:

1. It wouldn't normally be a requirement that they be a doctor.
2. I imagine speaking multiple languages would be a benefit (particularly speaking English in a non-English-speaking country), but I can't see it being a formal requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably similar to the skills of a ceo, the position is about leadership, management, teamwork and being able to represent the University. Although an experience in academia might be tangentially useful in order to relate to the people working in the university, their job is so broad, they work with so many people on different levels that this is potentially irrelevant. 
You can look at previous people who held the position to work out whether certain universities have more specific requirements.

Comment: In the US, many university presidents will have their CV available online.